# Can you hide output from a (not-automatically generated) join table using Sequelize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

I am using Feathersjs backend framework with Sequelize as ORM. Using Sequelize join tables of n:m relations can be generated 'automatically' (from hereon called 'Approach A') with the `belongsToMany` association, however I followed an also advocated alternative approach ('Approach B'), i.e. explicitly defining the join table with 2 `belongsTo` associations and using `hasMany` associations from the two tables you want to join to the joint table.

This works fine. However my output looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 2,
    "group_id": 1,
    "Venues": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "capacity": "400",
            "venue_name": "Club Lotte",
            "venue_description": "Club in Rotterdam",
            "EmployeeVenues": {
                "employee_id": 1,
                "venue_id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "capacity": "400",
            "venue_name": "Club Dino",
            "venue_description": "Club in Rotterdam",
            "EmployeeVenues": {
                "employee_id": 1,
                "venue_id": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 2,
    "group_id": 1,
    "Venues": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "capacity": "400",
            "venue_name": "Club Lotte",
            "venue_description": "Club in Rotterdam"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "capacity": "400",
            "venue_name": "Club Dino",
            "venue_description": "Club in Rotterdam"
        }
    ]
}
```

When using [Approach A this exact same issue can be solved using the `through: { attributes: [] }` in the query](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8818). Can this also be achieved using Approach B?

Comment: Have you tried `joinTableAttributes: []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach B uses an intermediate model and uses `belongsTo`. There are no features from sequelize (kind of implicated in the question) that support to leave out the output of the intermediate model (the join table). I browsed through the sequelize code and did not find 'such thing'. The instruction videos of Eric Katz (I found 3 of them on m:n with sequelize) also do not show such a method. He simply processes the output with forEach statements to get the output he wants. See at the bottom of this picture.

[image]

So in short: no such feature in sequelize for Approach B.

Answer (score 2):

Need use attributes

```
Model.findAll({
    attributes: ['foo'],
    include: {
        attributes: ['bar'],
        model: JoinModelName,
    },
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Comment: I rechecked, I think it is not really working yet. I will check tomorrow.

Comment: I checked: not possible. Using your method you still would have to show 1 attribute of the join table, so effectively you keep this extra layer in your output.